# How to get the source of html in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
down='http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_71f3890901017hof.html'
file=urllib.urlopen(down).read()
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
body=root.xpath('//div[@class="articalContent  "]')[0]
print body.text_content()
```

When i run the code, what i get is the text content ,how can i get the html source code of it,not the text content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
html = lxml.html.tostring(node)
```

and please: read the basic documentation of the tools you are using first.